# Pass data from .cpp file to Objective c ViewController

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c++11, c++14

I have a class called Client which is written in C++, It receives the message from the server and whenever the message is received i want to show the alert to users that what text has received? Simply need to notify the message to controllers. I have searched many blocks i can't find any example. Can anyone please give me a sample code to pass data?

In .cpp file this function will be triggered when the message is received

```
void Client::processMessage(CMsg *message) {
    assert(message);

    Log("<- %s", message->HumanReadableDescription().c_str());
    Log("received message = %s",message->HumanReadableDescription().c_str());

    string text = receivedMeassage.substr(0, 4);
    if (text == "Text") {
        Log("Code entered");
        long position = receivedMeassage.find(":");
        string sub = receivedMeassage.substr(position+1);
        currentMessage = sub;
        receievedMessages = currentMessage;
        Log(sub);
    }
    Log(receivedMeassage);
}
```

If the text is received i want to show popup to the users.

Comment: In my answer I use `NSLog` because I don't know how do you want to show popup, probably with `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following declarations to Client.hpp:

```
typedef const void* Controller;
typedef void (*OnMessageProcessed)(Controller, const std::string&);
```

Add the following properties to `Client`:

```
Controller messageHandler;
OnMessageProcessed onMessageProcessed;
```

When you want to show popup (for example, at the end of `Client::processMessage`) call `onMessageProcessed(messageHandler, receivedMessage);`.

Initialise `Client` with this code:

```
Client client;
client.messageHandler = (__bridge Controller)self; // self is your UIViewController instance
client.onMessageProcessed = onMessageProcessed;
```

Declare the following global function in `YourCustomViewController.mm`:

```
void onMessageProcessed(Controller controller, const std::string& message) {
    YourCustomViewController* viewController = (__bridge YourCustomViewController*)controller;
    [viewController onMessageProcessed:message];
}
```

Add `onMessageProcessed` to `YourCustomViewController`:

```
@interface YourCustomViewController: UIViewController
- (void)onMessageProcessed:(const std::string&)message;
@end

- (void)onMessageProcessed:(const std::string&)message {
    NSLog(@"%s", message.c_str());
}
```

Comment: You are probably better off keeping the strings on the Objective-C-side as `NSString` and turning the C++ into Objective-C++ (`.mm`) and converting `std::string` into `NSString` there.  Also pass `std::string` by `const` ref :)  Other than that, good answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe Replaced `std::string` with `const std::string&`. Not sure if we can turn Client.cpp into Client.mm because this class can be used on different platforms.

Comment: Yeah you need some glue code that is implemented within a `.mm` file as that's the only way to bridge C++ and Objective-C.  Doesn't have to be the whole class though.

Comment: @trojanfoe Let's wait for Arun's feedback.

Comment: I have converted the .cpp file into .mm file so it's made me easy to access the strings. Thanks for the answer @trojanfoe and Roman.